# Cannot assign Support cases to certain users through the Salesforce app

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, assignment-rules

The Salesforce app is very useful for assigning sales cases when not in front of a computer.

However, not everyone doing support is listed here which means that you can only assign to certain selection of people. Missing users are under the same profiles as others. Individual user settings looks the same too compared to other users appearing on the list.

Is it a bug? or a settings i don't know about. Thanks

Comment: You're using it while connected to the internet right ? Else it may be a matter of not all users being cached in your offline data.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke thanks a lot, i think it solved the issue, you were true that users were cached.